# Where should I use “that is”, “it is” and “to be”?

Tags: grammar

I just asked about the use of "to be", I think it is more clear to me, but I still have doubts. For instance I just saw a movie when someone said

"I want a room that is clean"

but sometimes the use "it is" instead of "that is" and sometimes they use "to be"

in spanish all that options means the same

Where should I use each?

Comment: Because you have not given examples of **all** the usages being asked about, it is impossible to answer. I am **guessing** that you are asking about "I want a room that is clean" and "I want it to be cleaned," where "it" refers to some specific room. Is that guess correct?

Comment: You'll have to explain your question more clearly, with examples. In some contexts "that" and "it" are both pronouns, and may be interchangeable (though often not). But in your example sentence, "that" is a subordinator, and certainly cannot be replaced by "it". I don't understand what role you mean "to be" to take.