# How Can I know if is "that is" "it is" "to be"?

Tags: grammar

I do not know when to correctly use the expressions "to be" "that is" or "it is"

In Spanish, all that means "que sea"

For example:

1)

> I want you to be honest with me
>
> Quiero **que seas** honesto conmigo

2)

> I want a room that is big"
>
> Quiero una habitación **que sea** grande

3)

> I dont like it but I hope it is good for you
>
> No me gusta, pero espero **que sea** bueno para ti

How can I know when do I have to use "to be", "that is" or "it is"?

Comment: Very possible dupe of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216775/where-should-i-use-that-is-it-is-and-to-be?rq=1

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi Unless the questions are exact duplicates, for example if someone accidentally posted the same question twice, duplicates should have at least one upvoted answer. It’s a good idea to look for duplicates before answering something that seems like a common problem learners face, so thanks for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 'To be', in the context of your sentence, is used to link the property of honesty to the pronoun, 'you'. Basically, it's saying: *I want you to have the property of honesty*. The infinitive is used, because to 'want' is a modal verb.
- 'That is' is used to create a subordinate clause - one that can be removed from the sentence without ruining grammatical correctness. We could therefore break the sentence *I want a room that is big* down to *I want a room. I want the room to be big.* This way, it's clear to see that 'That is' is being used as a shorthand way to reference a property that is **inherently part of the noun** - the key distinction between 'to be' and 'that is' is that 'to be' is asking for a property to be set to a pre-existing object: the English equivalent of "You know the room? Make it big.", while 'that is' is more like "I would like a big room", where 'big' is part of the noun upon its creation. If you know code, you could imagine this is the difference between `room.big = true` and `room = new BigRoom()`, where as you can see, `BigRoom` is different from `room.big`. Another way to think about is like this: 'to be' refers to a specific object, while 'that is' refers to a noun in general.
- 'It is' is the odd one out here. While 'that is' and 'to be' refer to setting some property of the noun being mentioned, 'it is' refers to *getting* the property (at least in your context). We can therefore break *I hope it is good for you* down to be *I hope that it has the property of goodness*. An alternative example would be *I cannot tell it is wet*, which we could break down as *I cannot see **if** it has the property of wetness* - note the keyword *if* which turns it into a conditional there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, kinda helped me with my problem, although I am not really sure about the difference, like in an essay or speaking I think I'll have problems telling the difference. For instance "We need a doctor to be good" is the translations of DeepL of "Quiero un doctor que sea bueno" while "We need a room that is good" is the translation of "Quiero un doctor que sea bueno" Both are nouns but the are different in translation

Answer (score 0):

- *To be* expresses a property that a noun will have in the future:
  *The shoe is to be green*
- *That is* can basically add an adjective to the end of a sentence.
  In Spanish, you use "de" to add an adjective (*Zapato de verde*); in English, you would say:
  *The shoe that is green*.
- *It is* declares a property upon a noun:
  *The shoe is green*